# trying to building on OSX but got "No rule to make target antlr4_static" error

Tags: empirical-lang

trying to build on OSX, got the following antlr error. Need to install antlr-runtime?

```
[ 43%] Built target antlr4_runtime
[ 43%] Built target csv_infer
[ 45%] Performing build_static step for 'antlr4_runtime'
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `antlr4_static'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime-stamp/antlr4_runtime-build_static] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/antlr4_runtime-build_static.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [dev] Error 2
```

Comment: You won't need install ANTLR; dependencies are already in `thirdparty/`. To confirm, you ran `make` (or `./scripts/build.sh`) from the root `empirical-lang` directory?

Comment: Yes, I did try both of them.

Comment: I want to see if this is purely an ANTLR build issue. (The reason you don't need to install ANTLR is that it is built for you automatically.) Can you try the following? `cd thirdparty/antlr/; unzip antlr4-master.zip; cd antlr4-master/runtime/Cpp; mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make -j8`

Comment: this works all good.

Comment: The build fails with the latest CMake (3.14.4), but works with the previous version (3.13.5). Bug report filed [here](https://github.com/empirical-soft/empirical-lang/issues/9).

Comment: you are right. 3.13.5 works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/empirical-soft/empirical-lang/pull/10).

CMake 3.14 changed where the `ExternalProject` module builds the source. It was unable to find ANTLR's own CMake files, necessitating a change to the `WORKING_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the fast fix

Comment: @TyLiu You can "accept" this answer by clicking the green check mark. That will indicate that your question has been resolved.